# Assign unique IDs by group, according to pattern

Tags: r

I have a grouped dataset, but the groups don't have a unique identifier, like this:

```
direction <- c('N','S','W','N','N','S','W','N','S','W')
measurement <- c(4,6,1,7,2,4,7,4,1,4)
x <- data.frame(direction, measurement)
x
   direction measurement
1          N           4
2          S           6
3          W           1
4          N           7
5          N           2
6          S           4
7          W           7
8          N           4
9          S           1
10         W           4
```

In `x`, the values for `direction` are in order, and each repeating set of 'N', 'S', and 'W' are a group.

Each set of values for `direction` always will start with 'N', however, not all groups will have a complete set of 'N', 'S', and 'W' rows (see `ID` B below).

Another way of phrasing this: I want to give a unique ID to each set of up to 3 rows starting where `direction == 'N'`.

The desired result is this:

```
    direction measurement ID
1          N            4  A
2          S            6  A
3          W            1  A
4          N            7  B
5          N            2  C
6          S            4  C
7          W            7  C
8          N            4  D
9          S            1  D
10         W            4  D
```

Note that `ID` B only has a row for 'N'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get this result with `==` to identify elements with "N" and `cumsum` to construct indices. Then pull out the values from the stored vector LETTERS as suggested in balter's answer.

Here, `cumsum` sums over a logical vector, coercing it to numeric binary (1s, and 0s). It thus repeats the same value and increments any time an "N" was encountered.

```
 x$ID <- LETTERS[cumsum(x$direction == "N")]
```

This returns

```
x
   direction measurement ID
1          N           4  A
2          S           6  A
3          W           1  A
4          N           7  B
5          N           2  C
6          S           4  C
7          W           7  C
8          N           4  D
9          S           1  D
10         W           4  D
```

Comment: Nice.  Did not think about `cumsum`.  Clever.

Comment: @Imo, I can't believe you solved this with one line of code. But can you explain how exactly `cumsum` is working here? I read the documentation for it and still can't make sense of this. Thanks!

Comment: @holastello I added a bit of text for an explanation. Maybe the best way to see what is going on  is to try out the code in stages. First, `x$direction == "N"` and then `cumsum(x$direction == "N")`. This result is fed as an index to `LETTERS`, a stored vector.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work:

```
direction <- c('N','S','W','N','N','S','W','N','S','W')
measurement <- c(4,6,1,7,2,4,7,4,1,4)
x <- data.frame(direction, measurement)

inds <- which(direction == 'N')
diffs <- diff(c(inds, length(direction)+1))

groups <- rep(seq_along(inds),diffs)

x$ID <- LETTERS[groups]
x
```

Note that if you have more than 26 groups, `LETTERS[]` will start returning NA.  You can always just use:

```
x$ID <- groups
```

If that happens.